# O que é ficar à ucha?

Tags: etimologia, palavra-para-ideia, regionalismo

[Ficar à ucha no Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ficar%20%C3%A0%20ucha) é:

> (francês *huche*, arca) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Caixa ou casa em que se guardam géneros alimentícios.
> 2. [Regionalismo]  Queimada de urze. = FOGUEIRA, QUEIMA
>
> **ficar à ucha**
>
> • Ficar sem nada.

Se ucha é uma arca ou caixa onde se coloca comida, como é que ficar à ucha significa ficar sem nada? Onde é que esta expressão é utilizada? (Não encontrei exemplos concretos no Google...)

Existem outras expressões mais comuns com o significado de ficar sem nada?

Comment: Nunca tinha *ouvido* isso antes. Existe *com uma mão a frente e outra atrás*.

Comment: Também nunca ouvi tal coisa.

Comment: Segundo o Abade de Baçal, “Em Freixo de Espada à Cinta, antigamente, os raparigos quando iam defecar no campo tinham de ficar distantes uns dos outros, de forma que, estendendo os braços, apenas tocassem a ponta dos dedos uns com os outros; por isso diziam: dá cá a ucha!, para regular a distância”.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo interessante, então _ucha_ tem ainda outro significado com possível origem no norte de Portugal (Bragança, onde o [Abade de Baçal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abade_de_Ba%C3%A7al) viveu). Após esse excerto a _ucha_ é novamente referida?

Comment: Fonte de `Segundo o Abade de Baçal`: http://falaresdanossalingua.blogspot.pt/2010/12/ucha-pt-e-gz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Também nunca ouvi.

Encontrei uma possível explicação dada por Henz Kröll no [tomo XIII](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/lingua-1/240-240/file.html) do *Boletim de Filologia* do Centro de Estudos Filológicos da Universidade de Lisboa (1952: 12):

> A. C. Moreno [*Revista Lusitana*] V, pág. 111, regista para Trás-os-Montes *ficar à ucha* (*ucha* = «*queimada de urze*» ¿gal. «arca»?) [...]. Com *ficar à ucha*, parece-nos relacionar-se a loc. beir. *ficar à ústia* «ficar sem nada, ficar logrado» [citando o *Novo diccionário da língua portuguesa* de Cândido de Figueiredo] em que sobrevive na linguagem popular uma das raras derivações do Lat. *urere*.

Não sei bem o que significa *ústia* (o tal dicionário apenas refere que se usa na expressão *ficar à ústia*, mas o presumível ético latino da  palavra significa [*arder*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uro#Latin)).

Quanto a expressões mais comuns com o mesmo significado, o artigo que referi menciona outras:

- *ficar a chuchar no dedo*,
- *ficar à divina*,
- *ficar em trinca* (Trás-os-Montes),
- *ficar a tocar o beato*,
- *ficar a olhar p´rò sinal*,
- *ficar a paz de pílulas*,
- *ficar a ver navios (do Alto de St.ª Catarina)*

Destes só conhecia *chuchar no dedo* e *a ver navios*.

Comment: Muito interessante (já agora é a página 17 do pdf), obrigado! É então uma expressão de Trás-os-Montes. Ainda a respeito de "ficar a ver navios" referem "levar uma rolha" como equivalente. Uma pequena especulação da minha parte: _ústia_ soa também a [¡_hostia_!](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/hostia), talvez devido à proximidade a Espanha, considerando um emprego mais vulgar das palavras, estas poderão ter tido alguma relação neste sentido.

Comment: "ficar a arder" significa ficar sem nada, mas também pode significar facr com o problema nas mãos.